# Решить пример на С++

Tags: c++

Не получается описать данный пример на С++, пытался через массивы, но получалась полная каша.

p=(1-1/22)*(1-1/32)...(1-1/n2)
n = (n>2).

Comment: поэтому теперь - давайте вы здесь

Comment: Понять вопрос - это уже 50% от выполненной задачи.

Comment: Получается только сделать такой вывод 1-1/1*2 
1-1/2*2 
1-1/3*2 
1-1/4*2 
1-1/5*2 А это все нужно еще умножить друг на друга.

Comment: Приведите примеры входных данных и результата. Покажите попытку решения и объясните, что с ней не так.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 #include <cmath>

double f(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
        return -1.0;

    double value = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        value *= (1 - 1 / pow(i, 2));
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%1.9f \n", f(i));
}
```

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c840124/v840124001/52276/VMmcOd8KYf0.jpg не получилось

Comment: Конечно не получилось, во первых в вас условие почемуто `n>=2`, а что вы хотели сделать в последнем цикле мне решительно не понятно. 
Можно же было чуть-чуть  подумать прежде чем код копипастить

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.